# scope: How to use a random number used in several methods

Tags: c#, scope

Trying to learn som C# by coding my first program. I have a problem though concerning the scope of variables.

What i want to do, is to generate a random number between 10000 and 99999 and use the result in several independent events in the same class.

I had no problems generating a random number:

```
 public string shuffle()
        {
            Random RandomNumber = new Random();
            int shuffleUdTemp = RandomNumber.Next(10000, 99999);
            string shuffleUd = shuffleUdTemp.ToString();
            return shuffleUd;
        }
```

Lets say that shuffle() results in 48532 - how can i use this number in several independent events in the same class (windows form)?

Please note that i am a total beginner in C# so i might have used some inprecise/wrong words.

Thx in advance :)

/Torben

Comment: How often do you need a new random number?

Comment: @user1449307 - You do understand your `shuffle()` is not required to use the `Random` class correct?  Just store the the result of `RandomNumber.Next(10000, 99999)` equal a string property of your class.  You should NOT call `Random RandomNumber = new Random();` in the same method or code block as `RandomNumber.Next(10000, 99999)` you won't appreciate the results.

Answer (score 4):

You can store it in a field

```
class MyRandomClass
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        mRandomNumber = RandomNumber.Next(10000, 99999);
    }

    public void Foo2()
    {
        //do something with mRandomNumber
    }

    private int mRandomNumber;
}
```

MyRandomClass can be of course your application, your window or any other class.

Comment: Was just posting similar answer, but since you already posted it +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to return that number and then just pass it into the functions that use that number

Comment: He's talking about storing the number so that a new one isn't generated, not what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a **static** member

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a variable or field. I. e.

```
class Test
{
    private string random = (new Random()).Next(10000, 99999).ToString();
    private string saver = "";
    public void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(random);
    }
    protected void otherMethod()
    {
        saver += random;
        Console.WriteLine(saver);
    }
}
```